# Construction of Cut off function $\psi$ such that $|\psi'(x)||\psi(x)| < \frac{1}{6}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, convolution

Let $L>0$. Is it possible to find  $0<\varepsilon <L$ and a cut off function $\psi: [0,L]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

i) $\psi \in C^3([0,L])$,

ii) $\psi(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,\varepsilon]$,

iii) $\psi(x)=1$ for all $x \in [L-\varepsilon, L]$,

and $$|\psi'(x)||\psi(x)| < \frac{1}{6}, \quad \forall x  \in [0,L]?$$

Remark: If $L \leq 3$, such function doesn't exist. (In this case is easy to obtain a contradiction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the density function $f(t) = 140 t^3 (1-t)^3$, $t\in [0,1]$. Then the CDF $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = 35 x^4 - 84 x^5 + 70 x^6 - 20 x^7$, satisfies:
\begin{align}
1) & \quad F(0) = 0,\, F(1) = 1\\
2) & \quad F^{(k)}(0) = F^{(k)}(1) = 0, \quad k\in{1,2,3}\\
3) & \quad F(x), F^\prime(x) \ge 0 \mbox{  for  } x\in[0,1] \\
4) & \quad \max_{x\in[0,1]}{F(x) F^\prime(x)} \le 2
\end{align}

Now you can define (taking $\varepsilon < \frac12 L$):
$$
\psi(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x<\varepsilon;\\
F\left(\frac{x-\varepsilon}{L-2\varepsilon}\right) & \varepsilon\le x\le L-\varepsilon;\\
1 & x>L-\varepsilon.
\end{cases}
$$
By the scaling of the function $\psi(x)$ (and its derivative), we have
$\max_{x\in[0,L]} \psi(x) \psi^\prime(x) \le \frac{2}{L-2\varepsilon}$. So this will be small if $L$ is sufficiently large.